# Is it possible to force a page to load the next page before running the rest of the code in my shopping bot code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, bots

I am creating a bot to purchase a parking pass and I can't call the function to fill out the second step of payment because the bot can't grab the fields that it needs to enter data into because the page that the fields are on haven't loaded. So, could I force the page to load the next step/page and then run my function?

I have tried to do a count so that after the click happens and it goes to second step of payment and runs the program again it runs the function, but this didn't work because the variable gets reset back to zero once the second step of payment page loads.  I noticed that the button on the first page runs an `ajaxRequest()` when it is clicked and then it goes to the second but I am not familiar with ajax, but I would assume there may be a solution to my problem using it.  I have tried putting pauses into the program to see if it just needs to wait but the pause just stops the progression to the next step in the payment process.  I am not sure if anyone can access this website because it is school related but the link is: https://www.schoolpay.com/parent/pay for the actual payment part.  The home page is https://www.schoolpay.com

```
function fillOutBill(){

    var creditCardNum = "0000000000000000";
    var expMonth = "01"; // a string in format with two digits ex. 01, 02, 11, 12
    var expYear = "2019"; // a string in format with four digits from 2019 to 2039
    var ccvNum = "000"; // a string in format with 3 digits from 000 to 999 ex. 123

    console.log("start of filling out the bill");
    //click the credit card dropdown
    var creditButton = document.getElementsByClassName("payment-button cc");
    creditButton[0].click();

    console.log("credit drop down clicked");

    //fill out credit card info
    creditCardBox = document.getElementById("cc_pan");
    creditCardBox.value = creditCardNum;
}


if (url == "https://www.schoolpay.com/parent/pay"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("mpn-button6 blue to-step-2 fl-right")[0].click();


    fillOutBill(); 
}
```

Once I get to the payment screen I click to the second step of payment and it runs the rest of the code before advancing to the next screen.  I need to run the `fillOutBill()` function after it goes to the next step but the link doesn't change so I can't do a redirect with a `chrome.runtime.sendmessage()` like I have done elsewhere in my program. Running this function results in this error,

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"

which tells me that the page hasn't loaded yet because it can't find its elements.

Please ask me to clarify if anything is unclear.

Comment: Maybe I could run another file at the end of this file so that the new page loads and then I can run fillOutBill().  I am researching on if this is possible right now. If someone knows a way please tell me.